# r: extracting data from a data frame using sapply

Tags: r

I have the data frame df which is structured the following way:

```
df
.. $data1
.. .. $data12
.. .. $data13
.. $data2
.. .. $1
.  . .. .. $something1
.. .. .. $something2
.. .. .. $something3
.. .. $2
.. .. .. $something1
.. .. .. $something2
.. .. .. $something3
```

I use:
     something1 <- sapply(df$data2, function(x) x$something1, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

to extract the data for each number. What I can't figure out is how to extract the number and store it as an ID for the extracted data (1 for the first dataset etc.)

Comment: Are you sure that's a proper data.frame? It doesn't seem to follow the data.frame rules. It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data (via `dput`) and the desired output for that input so possible solutions can be tested.

Comment: What @MrFlick said and shouldn't it be `x$1$something1`?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that I was dealing with a list not a data frame. And to extract the names of the objects I simply used

```
names(df$data2)
```

to extract the ID.